# Meteor data not updated on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm having an issue getting Meteor to update properly. My template is as follows:

```
  <template name="hello">
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
     <table>
        {{#each items}}
        {{>demoRow}}
        {{/each}}
     </table>
  </template>
  <template name="demoRow">
     <tr>
     <td>{{order}}</td>
     <td>
          <input type="text" class="nameChanger" name="demoName-{{name}}" data-demoname="{{name}}"     style="width: 90px" value="{{name}}"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </template>
```

The script file looks like the following:

```
Template.hello.items = function () {
      var entity= Entities.findOne(Session.get('entityId'));
      if(entity!=null) {
         return Entities.findOne(Session.get('entityId')).items;
      }
      return null;
   };
Template.hello.events({
      'change .nameChanger': function(evt) {
          var $tgt = $(evt.target)
          var entity=Entities.findOne(Session.get('entityId'));
          var items = entity.items;
          var tgtName = $tgt.data('demoname');
          var newName = $tgt.val();
          var found=false;
          for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
              var item=items[i];
              if(item.name == tgtName) {
                  item.name =newName;
                  found=true;
              }
          }
          if(!found) {
              alert("Cannot find ",tgtName);
          }
          Entities.update({_id: entity._id}, {$set: { items: items}});
      },
    });
```

Finally, my initial value is set up as:

```
Entities.insert( { type: 'test',
                 items: [
                     {name: 'value1'},
                     {name: 'value2'},
                     {name: 'value3'}
                     ]
             }
         );
```

This renders a table of text inputs. When I change one of the text fields, it automatically updates the entities collection and the display shows the correct data.  However, if I try to change the same field a second time, my alert will trigger as it cannot find the value.

The really interesting part is that `tgtName` has the original, unchanged value. Yet, evt.target has the correct, updated data set with the new name.  I can even get the correct name via `evt.target.dataset['demoname']` which is the workaround I have in place.

My question is, why id `$tgt.data()` not hold the updated values?

I should mention that this does update other windows appropriately and if I update it in one window and then update the same value in another, it does work appropriately, first time. After that, both windows seems to house the value they had at the first update.  It's almost like some kind of scope issue, but I can't figure out where.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of jQuery with Meteor (or any other thing that tries to modify the data attribute)

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

So, the option are to NOT user jQuery and access the `evt.target.dataset['demoname']` as stated, or to use the jQuery.attr()

```
$tgt.attr("data-demoname")
```

Thanks to mizzao and dgreensp at meteor for help on this (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2329)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but maybe the update is doing something wrong. Maybe you could try just updating the single edited item. Try this:

```
Template.hello.events({
  'change .nameChanger': function(evt) {
      var $tgt = $(evt.target)
      var entity=Entities.findOne(Session.get('entityId'));
      var items = entity.items;
      var tgtName = $tgt.data('demoname');
      var newName = $tgt.val();
      var found=false;
      for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
          var item=items[i];
          if(item.name == tgtName) {
              item.name =newName;
              found=true;
              break;
          }
      }
      if(!found) {
          alert("Cannot find ",tgtName);
      }
      else
        Entities.update({_id: entity._id}, {$set: { 'items.' + i.toString(): item}});
  },
});
```

A bit clunky, but maybe...

Comment: Thanks, and I'll try it, but 1) The update is definitely working, as other browser windows see the update's effect. and 2) My real code does a lot more then just update the name, this was just a proof of concept.